# Is it possible to specify multiple recipients in mailto via Action.OpenUrl at Apaptive cards

Tags: mailto, adaptive-cards

I need to create email with several recipients by click on Action.OpenUrl, but syntax like below doesn't work.

```
"actions": [
    {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "Send email",
        "url": "mailto:someone@email.com;someoneelse@email.com?Subject=Test"
    }
]
```

Is there any way to create this kind of email?

Comment: Does it work for you if you try `mailto:someone@email.com`?

Comment: Yes, it worked, at least at the time of writing the question. I haven't tested this functionality for a long time